# Nakayama Conjecture. The commutative case.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

> Is the Nakayama conjecture solved in the commutative case? It states that "*if all the modules of a minimal injective resolution of an Artin algebra $R$ are injective and projective, then $R$ is self-injective*".

I tried to look up but could not find if it is solved or not solved in the commutative case. Can someone provide a reference if it is solved in the commutative case? The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakayama%27s_conjecture) does not say if it is solved in the commutative case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following remark can be found in *Morita Contexts, Idempotents, and Hochschild Cohomology
— with Applications to Invariant Rings* by Ragnar-Olaf Buchweitz ([arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301347)):

> Remarks 3.2. (1) The conjectures (INC’), (INC) trivially hold if the algebras
>   C,B involved are already commutative noetherian rings. However, there seems to
>   be no real advantage gained in either (SNC) or (GNC) if one assumes that A is
>   already commutative. In this sense, the aforementioned conjectures truly belong to
>   the realm of (slightly) noncommutative algebra.

Here, SNC denotes the strong Nakayama conjecture and GNC the generalized Nakayama conjecture. For their meaning, see loc. cit.

Comment: It says that INC(idempotent Nakayama Conjecture) is trivial, but it does not say that Nakayama conjecture is trivial or solved.

Answer (score 1):

A commutative artin algebra is a product of local algebras. The Nakayama conjecture is trivial for local non-selfinjective algebras since the injective envelope of the regular module can not be projective.